# How to get sum of values in grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

For example I have grid.

```rb
//grid for answers_for_online
var answersGridForOnline5 = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id          : 'grid_for_stats',
    store       : storez3,
    columns     : answers_columns5,
});
```

my column:

```
var answers_columns5 = [{
    id: "idz",
    header: 'idz',
    dataIndex: "idz",
    renderer: fun_f
}];
```

and renderer function

```
function fun(n, j, k, m, h, i) {
    var count = store.snapshot ? store.snapshot.length : store.getCount()

    var cez = k.get("scale")
    var ce =  ( 2 / count ) * 100

    return ce + " % "
}
```

Question: In database  I have for example: scales (that user answered on scale-question)

```
id | scale
1  |  4
2  |  4
3  |  1
4  |  2
```

How i can sum scales (and group them of course) and put this in my grid? 
For example in my grid i should get:

```
scale | scale %
1     |  25%
2     |  25%
4     |  50%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you don't attempt to do it inside Grid/Store. Instead process the data before loading it to store - for example do it in database with GROUP BY statement.

Comment: yeah, i think the same, but how i can SUM data for scale: 1, for scale 2 and for scale 3 ?

Comment: Well.. you are talking about summing but you really mean counting. So in SQL you would just write: `SELECT scale, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY scale`

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of values in a store, you can use [Store.sum()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum)